# Is there any difference where we specify includes in Rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am surprised with includes method behaviour. let's take example

**case 1:**

```
User.includes(:organizations, :category, subscriptions: :plan).coaches
```

> Time taken: 200ms

**Case 2:**

```
User.coaches.includes(:organizations, :category, subscriptions: :plan)
```

> Time taken: 20 ms

Both cases where executed without cache.

Is make difference where we specify includes ?

Comment: "is there any difference" - this is __trivial__ to check. Just watch your server log for the queries made, and compare them.

Comment: If User is the class name and coaches a has_many relation, I am surprise that those calls work at all